# TableSorter filer functionality

Tags: tablesorter

I am wondering if I can have "!Peter" option while filering on the first column of the first table example [here?](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html)

I should be able to have all other options + !Peter ?

Thanks in advance,

Aparna

Answer (score 0):

The demo you linked would not allow you to enter and search for `!Peter` because:

- The first column (with "Peter" in it) is set up to use a select element.
- You could enter `!Peter` in the second column, but it *would not* return any results because that column is set up to only return exact matches.

I set up [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4418/) without either of those restrictions, and if you enter `!Peter` into either of the first two columns, the expected results will show.

Now, if you mean you want to change the select element options, then you should look at the documentation for the [`filter_selectSource` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#widget-filter-selectsource).